# Scraping the lazy dynamically loading page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I need to make scrape the assortment, but page is loading dynamically. It loads new elements when you scroll down the page. I make autoScroll func, it increased count of items. When I up delay or distance of autoScroll I get error:

`TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed`

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 
async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 100; 
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
          var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
          window.scrollBy(0, distance);
          totalHeight += distance;
 
          if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve();
          }
        }, 100); 
      });
    });
  }
 
async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: `wss://chrome.browserless.io` });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://a201910091655256231033.szwego.com/static/index.html#/shop_detail/A201910091655256231033', {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
  await autoScroll(page);
 
  let combinedData = [];
  const textElements = await page.$$('.word-break');
  const imageElements = await page.$$('.lazy');
 
  for (let i = 0; i < textElements.length; i++) {
    const text = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim(), textElements[i]);
    let imageUrl = null;
    if (i < imageElements.length) { 
      imageUrl = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('data-original').trim(), imageElements[i]);
    }
    combinedData.push({ text: text, imageUrl: imageUrl });
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(combinedData, null, 2), combinedData.length);
  await browser.close();
}
 
scrape().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the particular issue using puppeteer.
But we can easily and efficently extract all the details needed using plain JS or any of your favourite programming language.

The website lazy loads by making a POST request with the timestamp from which the posts needs to be fetched.

For example, take the first request for `/album/personal/all` by inspecing the network tab in the browser,
Make a POST request

POST https://a201910091655256231033.szwego.com/album/personal/all?&albumId=A201910091655256231033&searchValue=&searchImg=&startDate=&endDate=&sourceId=&slipType=1&timestamp=1652766383948&requestDataType=&transLang=en

with the following Form Data

`tagList=[]`

The response of the POST request is an JSON response,

You can extract all the details needed from this JSON Document. Parse and extract the required details like images, text etc., which is structured and ready to use.

To Fetch the next set of posts, you should make another POST request by changing the `timestamp` query parameter in the URL.

Under `result.pagination.pageTimestamp` in the previous JSON Response Body, you will find the next request timestamp.
When making next request, you can substiture, `timestamp=1652766383948` with the new timestamp value and fetch older posts untill `result.pagination.isLoadMore` is false in any response.

You can use plain JS fetch to make this request.